# Missing header file linux/io_uring.h

Tags: linux, c, programming, api

```c
#include <linux/io_uring.h>
```

```
main.c:1:10: fatal error: linux/io_uring.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/io_uring.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Kernel version 5.4.0-80.

I have not found a way to install the API header files. The ABI should be supported though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Ubuntu (which I’m guessing is what you’re using, based on the kernel version), you’ll find `linux/io_uring.h` in [`linux-libc-dev`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/linux-libc-dev). Install that:

```
sudo apt install linux-libc-dev
```

and you should find the header in `/usr/include/linux`.

Programs written using `liburing` use that library’s headers, so installing that is unlikely to help; but if you want to try, the relevant package is `liburing-dev`. The `io_uring.h` header there defines the same interface as the kernel UAPI’s `io_uring.h`.

Answer (score 1):

A development package for liburing likely needs installing, e.g. on CentOS it's  `luburing-develop`.  See example at https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-powertools-x86_64/liburing-devel-1.0.7-3.el8.x86_64.rpm.html

Also note that the include of `<linux/io_uring.h>` might need revising to be `<liburing/io_uring.h>` due to where the package has placed the file.